# How to rename files containing Korean characters in python

Tags: python, windows

I want to rename more than 100 files in windows 7, all of them have korean/hangul characters.
But os.rename() doesn't work with these files.

```
WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

I'm using python 2.6.5 and os.listdir() for getting the filenames which gives me something like `???? ??? 021? 061205`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Python?

What is your locale?

You are using `os.rename(src, dst)` ... what does `print repr(src)` give you for a typical file? Use `print(ascii(src))` with Python 3.x.

How are you getting `src` for each file? If it is some kind of "get me all the files in `some-folder`" gadget, have you supplied `some-folder` as a `unicode` object?

**Update:** If in fact you are doing something like:

```
for filename in os.listdir("C:\\foo\\bar\\baz"):
    dst = some_func(filename)
    os.rename(filename, dst)
```

you may like to do as indicated by the os.listdir docs and my earlier hint, and try this:

```
for filename in os.listdir(u"C:\\foo\\bar\\baz"):
    dst = some_func(filename)
    os.rename(filename, dst)
```

Comment: I'm using os.listdir() for getting the filenames.

Comment: @vivek: Please consider when asked to give the result of print repr(something), giving it EXACTLY via copy/paste, not "something like" with double quotes around it instead of single ones.